# Article created date shows 5 hours ahead to the current time

Tags: php, joomla, timezone

In phpinfo, default.timezone & default.datetime as America/New_york.

In joomla configuration file offset as "America/Newyork". Offset user as "UTC". In backend user setting as "Newyork."

Actually the problem as When i create a article, the time save as as UTC format in database, But when we view the created date in the article, it shows 5 hours ahead to the created time. Whenever i save the article it increase 5 hours from the current date.

Please advice.. Thank you.

Comment: you need to fix the php default timezone

Answer (score 0):

Add this line as the first line in your code,

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Change the timezone (`'Asia/Kolkata'`) to your timezone.
You can check your timezone name [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

If it is specific about Joomla, then

using `JHtml::('date' , ....)` for output

https://compojoom.com/blog/entry/how-to-use-jdate

Also, When you call `JFactory::getDate()` it will construct a `JDate` object, which already takes the timezone into account.

More info:

- http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_JDate
- http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDate.html
- http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFactory.html#method_getDate

Comment: yes nirav, you are correct. But it will not work in  joomla, i tried this. By default joomla store the values in UTC time format. while i view the saved date in backend article section, it shows 5 hours ahead.. This is the problem we are facing..

Comment: @Kathirvel, Updated the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue in the server timezone. I have changed the server timezone to GMT/UTC. it was working fine. Thanks for all your contribution